# Replace only numeric values

Tags: python, dataframe

I have to replace only numeric values in column C to "profit", if C.values is greater than 50

I have the following code but it replaces everything, not just the numeric values

```
df['C'].values[df['C'].values >= 50] = 'Profit'
```

My dataframe

```
A       B       C
test    NaN     xyz
hit     NaN     10
hit     NaN     90
hit     NaN     abc
test    val     20
test    val     90
```

My output

```
A       B       C
test    NaN    Profit
hit     NaN     10
hit     NaN     Profit
hit     NaN     Profit
test    val     20
test    val    Profit
```

My desired output

```
A       B       C
test    NaN    xyz
hit     NaN     10
hit     NaN     Profit
hit     NaN     abc
test    val     20
test    val     Profit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more terse solution could be:

`df['C'][df['C'].apply(lambda x: x > 50 if isinstance(x, int) else False)] = 'Profit'`

Answer (score 3):

I would use `.apply()` here, with both a try-except and an if-else block.

Something like:

```
def convert_to_profit(value):
    try:
        if int(value) >= 50:
            return 'Profit'
        else:
            return value
    except ValueError:
        return value

df.loc[:, 'C'] = df['C'].apply(convert_to_profit)
```

The try-except block will allow you to catch non-numeric values and return the non-replaced value.

Comment: Good answer, though I think separating the two tests (is a number and is greater than 50) would be more readable :)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the dataframe rows and edit each line when needed:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        if int(row['C']) >= 50:
            row['C'] = 'Profit'
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

From pandas docs:

> [df.iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)
>   Iterate over DataFrame rows as (index, Series) pairs.